# Graphic software

Tags: math-software

Can somebody recomend me a software(preferably free) to draw a graphic like this:

[image: diagram]

I have downloaded GeoGebra, but it seems I can't use it to draw such a graphic.

Comment: inkscape is free, and if you're dedicated, it can be used to make graphics such as these. It's inbuilt latex support is a bit poor, but these are things that one gets used to.

Comment: Also you should be able to draw something like this in GeoGebra

Comment: Dia is free and should allow this too. http://live.gnome.org/Dia

Answer (score 4):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) is a general purpose open source vector graphics tool, available for all the standard platforms. I have used it for a few years.   It works moderately well with LaTeX, and the price is right.   Using Inkscape to produce a picture like the one you posted would be routine. Some fiddling might need to be done to get good positioning of labels.

Answer (score 0):

- [vector field plot](http://User:Geek3/VectorFieldPlot)
- [plotdf from Maxima CAS](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_22.html#Item_003a-plotdf)

HTH